# References or texts for learning about the augmented lagrangian?

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am reading a paper about a convex model for non-negative matrix factorization. In the paper it describes how to do such a technique and it says that it uses the augmented Lagrangian.

I can't find any really detailed information about the augmented lagrangian. Does any one know of any references, texts or maybe have an intuitive explanation of how the augmented lagrangian works and how it was derived?

Thank you for any help comments in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about this in the [Nocedal and Wright](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387303030) book, more precisely in chapter 17. [Fletcher](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471494631) presents the method in chapter 12.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see my answer in the link below.

[what is the intuition behind the augmented lagrangian?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3440618/what-is-the-intuition-behind-the-augmented-lagrangian)

Following are some of the references (this list is highly incomplete).

[1] http://www.mit.edu/~dimitrib/Constrained-Opt.pdf

[2] https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00934777.pdf

[3] https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_slides.pdf

[4] https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf

[5] https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.3203